# NuGet (NuPack) intellisense (Visual Studio Package Manager Console)

Tags: .net, visual-studio, nuget

My intellisense for NuGet doesn't show up. Or maybe there is some kind of shortcut for it ?

Comment: What is this I don't even...  NuGet is a tool.  Tools don't have intellisense.  If you're asking where it is, right-click on your References and select "Add Package Reference..."  If that isn't there, restart VS.

Comment: No, there is a NuGet Console window which does have intellisense (or should do!)

Comment: Yeah. I was talking about this powershell-like console (Package Manager Console).

Comment: FYI - watch the video at http://nuget.codeplex.com/ and the need for this question becomes obvious.  You can see that there's an intellisense-like feature, but it doesn't work as you type or with ctrl+space which makes it seem broken.  Thanks @will below for the answer!

Comment: Tab is the standard for invoking command completion in shells (Powershell is a shell).  Should be a way to add key mapping to powershell in your profile for that host for other keystrokes to invoke command completion.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

I don't think the intellisense is what you expect, as in a dropdown with a list of available options.

[From this page](http://nuget.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Getting%20Started), it appears you have to hit <kbd>tab</kbd> in order to get command completion.

Comment: thx. "tab" is rather strange hint. I'm used to ReSharper and I was doing alt+space or ctrl+. and nothing worked =) thx. again.

Comment: mine is doesn't show up after I hit tab. Do ı need to configure something?

Comment: @tug don't know.  You might need to contact the nuget team if it isn't working.

Comment: That's because it's powershell tab completion, not intellisense.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure where you refer to intellisense. The answers above apply to the PowerShell console, which is tab completion.

If you refer to intellisense for the *.nuspec file, you only need to have the correct XSD and XmlNs declaration to get intellisense for the NuGet manifest xml file.

The NuSpec package might help you achieve this with ease.

Simply `Install-Package NuSpec`