# VS 2013 Professional Package Manager Console Intellisense Not Working

Tags: nuget, visual-studio-2013

I posted this to Nuget codeplex, but not sure how actively that is monitored and whether it'll just get lost.  Is intellisense still supposed to work in the console? Seeing blogs/videos from Hanselman and others showing it working but I either get no intellisense or incorrect intellisense (from my naïve understanding so far).

If I type 'install' and hit TAB, nothing comes up.  I've seen videos where Install-Package shows up.

If I type 'install-package ' and hit TAB, I'd expect it to be a list of packages from nugget.org.  However, in a blank mvc web project (WebApplication1), I get three things in a drop down: .\packages, .\WebApplication1, and .\WebApplication1.sln.  Not sure why it is pulling those up.

Finally, if I type 'install package el' and hit TAB, nothing is coming up. (I'd expect ELMAH - and possibly others to show up)

Am I misunderstanding the intellisense/autocomplete functionality provided by the console?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4133889/nuget-nupack-intellisense-visual-studio-package-manager-console

Comment: you have to hit tab in order to get command completion

Comment: I stated in my question that I hit TAB and nothing happens.